# How to use tamil fonts in php page?

Tags: php, fonts, webfonts, tamil

I have used Tamil fonts and it is displaying the correct font when I run it in local server. But it is showing like `X.Ãƒ.uhkrhÃ¤ buÂ£oahÂ®` in webpage. How to solve this? Please help.

Comment: You probably need to set/use `UTF-8`

Comment: thanks for your response. How to set/use UTF-8? and where i should set it

Comment: [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/a/279279/1700963)

Comment: still its not working friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this ,

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
```

Comment: it's been in the server side, not in the client/browser side.

Answer (score 3):

Add the below code on your php script.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
actually the file extension is only .php but everthing inside is html only.  when am editing the tamil content in dreamweaver/localhost it is perfect but not in server

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things

1. set meta data to utf-8 (as given in answers here)
2. Save the page in UTF-8 encoding instead of ASCII (then browser will know this page contains UTF-8 content)